# Symfony keeps all LDAP passwords available and valid for 5 minutes

Tags: symfony, security, active-directory, passwords

With my symfony project, i log my user trough ldap.
When i change LDAP (Active Directory) password (on the server, i cant with a form at this time), I can log in for a while with my most recent password and my old one (I don't know how long exactly).

```
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    #providers: responsable de charger les utilisateurs à partir d'une source de données : ex : MySQL, LDAP...
    providers:
        ldap:
            ldap:
                service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
                base_dn: 'DC=domain,DC=com'
                search_dn: '%env(LDAP_ADMIN_ACCOUNT)%'            
                search_password: '%env(LDAP_PASSWORD)%'
                default_roles: ROLE_USER         
                uid_key: sAMAccountName
        users_in_memory: { memory: null }
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: ldap
            form_login_ldap:
                service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
                login_path: app_login
                check_path : app_login
                dn_string: 'domain\{user_identifier}'
                enable_csrf: false
                username_parameter: login[username]
                password_parameter: login[password]
            logout:
                path: "logout"
                target: /login

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: '^/', roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS, requires_channel: https }

when@test:
    security:
        password_hashers:
            # By default, password hashers are resource intensive and take time. This is
            # important to generate secure password hashes. In tests however, secure hashes
            # are not important, waste resources and increase test times. The following
            # reduces the work factor to the lowest possible values.
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
                algorithm: auto
                cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
                time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
                memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon
```

Its not very safe.

I dont understand how to fix this issue.

Comment: Ok, so i can login with my newer an older password during 5 minutes

Comment: Ok so ive tried to change many php cache's var in php.ini but it doesnt work

Comment: Ok so ive tried to change many php cache's var in php.ini but it doesnt work